# How to create a static Mapview that recognize an onTap method

Tags: android, onclick, overlay, android-mapview

I'm trying to develop a layout that shows a Google Map with a route drawn on a Overlay layer associated with this map. I want this mapView to be a small static map that shows, as a thumbnail, the main route the user followed, and then if the user clicks on it, an intent takes you to a different activity displaying the map in full screen with the route and all the zoom functionalities.

The thing is that although I override the onTap method of the Overlay setting there the intent to the new activity, it only works if I set the MapView as setEnabled(true), but if I do so, then the thumbnail map can be dragged and moved by the user.

I'm sorry if it is not clear enough, but I don't know how to explain it better.

Thanks in advance

This is my customized class which extends Overlay and overrides the onTap method:

```
class MapOverlay extends Overlay {

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                RouteMapActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        return false;


    };
```

And this is my onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detailrun_activity);

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
    map.setEnabled(true);
    map.setClickable(true);
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = map.getOverlays();
    projection = map.getProjection();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

    double lat = 28.063119 * 1E6, longi = -82.41128 * 1E6;
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) lat, (int) longi);

    MapController myMapController = map.getController();
    myMapController.setCenter(point);
}
```

For now I'm only drawing a straight line between two GeoPoints, and I don't get any logcat errors.

The map with the route is indeed drawn, and the overrided onTap method works, but it seems it only recognizes the tap if my mapView is defined as enabled and clickable, but if I do so, then the user can also move and drag the map as long as he holds pressing the screen.

Comment: Show your code. And are you getting any errors in logcat with the present code, then show that as well.. My estimate would be that you are overriding a wrong method, onClick/onTab. Maybe you need to catch the onTouch event instead :)

Comment: Any other suggestion of how to block that MapView??

Comment: You still havn't shown any code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in stackoverflow, but I added my code just down here, as a new answer to myself because I didn't know how to post some code when responding your comment.

Comment: @Gonzo The usual way to do is simply to "edit" your original question.

Comment: Thanks @paradigmatic for the clarification. This is my code finally. Any suggestion on how to lock the view withouth disabling the mapoverlay??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get static google map image as per your location by [this link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=16&size=256x256&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C%2272.5%22,%2222.5%22&sensor=false). that you can display in imageview and click on that you can target new activity which have MapView.. i think it may be a good option for you.

Comment: I'm afraid this option doesn't fit me because I need to have access to the mapView functionalities to draw a route on it, and with this link it seems I can only specify the google map I want to display and not modifying it.